# how to fill missing values as zero

Tags: r

I have data that denotes 'X' as a missing value, and I want to fill these with zeros, then assort the data by `bcr_code` by selecting only bcr 27, 28, and 29.

I have tried

```
ebird %>% group_by(protocol_type) %>% select(common_name, observation_count, observation_date, bcr_code)
```

to get it into the `data.frame` format, but I want to group them by specific values onto a new data.frame, by only selecting a few values.

Reproducible code:

```
structure(list(protocol_type = c("Traveling", "Traveling", "Incidental", 
"Incidental", "Incidental", "Incidental"), common_name = c("Bachman's Sparrow", 
"Bachman's Sparrow", "Bachman's Sparrow", "Bachman's Sparrow", 
"Bachman's Sparrow", "Bachman's Sparrow"), observation_count = c("1", 
"1", "X", "2", "2", "X"), observation_date = structure(c(18004, 
18363, 11796, 13331, 13636, 13698), class = "Date"), bcr_code = c(27L, 
27L, 27L, 27L, 27L, 27L)), row.names = c(NA, -6L), groups = structure(list(
    protocol_type = c("Incidental", "Traveling"), .rows = structure(list(
        3:6, 1:2), ptype = integer(0), class = c("vctrs_list_of", 
    "vctrs_vctr", "list"))), row.names = 1:2, class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"), .drop = TRUE), class = c("grouped_df", 
"tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Equivalent in `dplyr`

```
library(dplyr)

ebird %>%
  mutate(observation_count = as.numeric(replace(observation_count, observation_count == "X", 0))) %>% 
  filter(bcr_code %in% c(27, 28, 29))
```

Answer (score 2):

In Base `R` you could:

```
# 0 instead of X

ebird[ebird$observation_count == "X", 3] <- 0

# only keep 27 | 28 | 29 

ebird <- ebird[ebird$bcr_code %in% c(27, 28, 29), ]

# which in this case keeps all given observations
```

Comment: I get this error when performing both code:`Error: Must subset columns with a valid subscript vector.
i Logical subscripts must match the size of the indexed input.
x Input has size 5 but subscript i has size 12243277.`. Might it be that it does not work on a larger dataset?

Comment: There is an error in the code: `ebird <- ebird[ebird$bcr_code %in% c(27, 28, 29), ]`. Missing comma

Comment: My bad just noticed the comma.